# How to get all the estimators from the Sklearn grid_search not just the best estimator?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I run a grid search on my training data with grid_params. In the end, I want to run predict_proba of a few best estimators on the test data but I can only get the best_estimator from grid_search [ grid_search_best_estimator_.predict_proba(X) ]

My question is "How can I run the predict_proba of first n estimators on a different data in scikit-learn grid_search?

Comment: Doesn't look like that's built in; you could iterate through the `grid_scores_` and get the `parameters` for different models, and manually fit each one. Better yet, you could set up a "poor man's" gridsearch then you don't have to fit the same estimators twice - that's not too difficult